# How to use Android for work's DO mode on Android M?

Tags: android

On Android L, when first boot the device or factory reset the device,we can set DO mode in the SetupWizard process.

While on Android M,google announced that AndroidForWork.apk is no longer needed and Supporting Device Owner mode is part of Google Play service.

So my question is that how to enter DO mode on Android M?

Comment: The premise of your question differs from my own experience with vanilla L on a Nexus 4.  There is no way to set the device owner in the setup wizard, but it also does not require any AndroidForWork.apk.  You make your app a device administrator in the normal way, then make it the device owner with an `adb` command.  AFAIK, this has not changed in M.

Comment: use what adb command? I have a moto nexus 6,it's based on android 6.0.I do not kown how to enter DO mode.

Comment: `adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.example.yourapp/.YourAdminReceiver`

Comment: YourAdminReceiver is ?

Comment: A class in your project that extends [`DeviceAdminReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html).  It needs a policy file, but it can be empty.  See [Device Administration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html).

Comment: Device Owner is a special Device Administrator.  It's made special by that `dpm` command.

Comment: I have got answer from google,we need to enable device owner on google admin,and then sign in the corp account in the setup wizard process.

Comment: "Enable Device Owner option during initial device setup" on admin.google.com.  Device Management->Mobile->Device management settings.

Answer (score 0):

Here all informations you need : [Device Owner Provisioning](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/provision.html#device_owner_provisioning_via_nfc)

Comment: Link are subject to expire please include information in your answer